# CSS: Placing Element Off Center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible with CSS to set the position of a `div` to 8px left of center?

The reason for my asking, is that JQuery Mobile sets divs to the right by about 8px, and I would like to center an element, which would require applying a left correction of 8px.

My CSS:

```
.sectionMap{
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW The padding values are space delimited... the commas aren't needed.

Comment: I updated the demo code. Do know know if this can be done without using JS?

Comment: Your best bet is to find out what class in jQM is causing the 8px shift and add a modified version of that class in your css with a margin-left:-8px or something. Otherwise, jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kinda hacky, but maybe something like this:

```
.sectionMap{
    width: 300px;
    display: block;

    position:relative;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-158px; /*Centered, minus 8px left*/

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/XVU5U/1/)

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution.